# NullPointerException when trying to reproduce example in Head First Servlets and JSP

Tags: java, servlets

I was reproducing the example in Head First Servlets and JSP Ch.5 that showed how Servlet Context Listener worked. After implementing the code from the book, I got `NullPonterException`.

> Servlet.service() for servlet [ListenerTester] in context with path [/ServletContextListenerPractice] threw exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I've checked several time and I'm sure that the codes are the same as those on the book, except for the file path. I setup the file path as `com.example.web` while the book uses `com.example`. Anyone knows what the problem is?

**ListenerTester.java**

```
package com.example.web;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ListenerTester
 */
@WebServlet("/ListenerTester")
public class ListenerTester extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    public ListenerTester() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("test context attributes set by listener<br>");
        out.println("<br>");

        Dog dog = (Dog) getServletContext().getAttribute("dog");

        // render brand name to client
        out.println("The brand is " + dog.getBreed());
    }

}
```

**Dog.java**

```
package com.example.web;

public class Dog {

    private String breed;

    public Dog(String breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    public String getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }
}
```

**MyServletContextListener.java**

```
package com.example.web;

import javax.servlet.*;

public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitilized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        ServletContext sc = event.getServletContext();
        String dogBreed = sc.getInitParameter("breed");

        Dog d = new Dog(dogBreed);

        // set Dog reference, d, as attribute on Servlet Context
        sc.setAttribute("dog", d);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ListenerTester</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.web.ListenerTester</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ListenerTester</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ListenTest.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>breed</param-name>
    <param-value>Beta</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        com.example.web.MyServletContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Is this the actual code, there is a typo in `contextInitilized` ?

Comment: `@Override` is your friend.

Comment: @DavidConrad I just add the annotation right before `doGet` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Berger I'm using `eclipse` IDE so I don't think there will be any typo undiscovered.

Comment: No, add `@Override` before `contextInitilized`, because without `@Override` the typo most definitely will be undiscovered. You will simply be creating a new, unique, different method, rather than overriding a method from the superclass.

Comment: @Berger You are right. I missed the possibility the compiler failed to catch the typo. My apology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misspelled `contextInitialized` but the compiler doesn't mind because you didn't tell it you intended to override a method from the superclass, `ServletContextListener`. If you add the `@Override` annotation to tell the compiler your intention, it will verify that you are in fact overriding a superclass method.

```
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override    // this one gives a compiler error because it doesn't override anything
    public void contextInitilized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // . . .
    }

    @Override    // this one doesn't complain because it does override a method
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // . . .
    }

    // this one compiles just fine, even though the name is spelled wrong
    public void contextInitilized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // . . .
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

It is perfectly legal to have a new method called `contextInitilized`; it is also perfectly useless, and will not do what you expect.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you. But here's another one. Why wouldn't compiler throw an error message if I didn't implement `contextInitialized` method in `MyServletContextListener` class since `ServletContextListener` is an Interface?

Comment: @EricHung The interface contains [default implementations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) of those methods.

Comment: Didn't lear that before. Thanks a lot!